# Fire javascript function when ctrl+p is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to destroy a jQueryUI tabs when somebody tries to print the page.
I can't hide it with CSS as I need the data from these tabs.

Can anyone help/point me in the right direction with this?
Perhaps there are other ways of achieving the same results?

By destroy i mean:

```
$('#tabs').tabs("destroy");
```

This has to work on IE7/8, as that is the browser used in the company.

Solution (Thanks to @Phil ):

```
//Destroys the tabs for print
window.onbeforeprint = destroyTabs;

//Remakes tabs after printing
window.onafterprint = makeTabs;


function makeTabs() {
    $('#tabs').tabs();
}

function destroyTabs() {
    $('#tabs').tabs('destroy');
}
```

Comment: So by "destroy" you mean undo the tabs effect but retain the data?

Comment: can we see a working example of what you have?

Comment: What happens if I print from the file menu?

Comment: I don't understand why hiding it with CSS would destroy the data. If you set `display: none;`, the data in the tabs is still accessable from JS... isn't it?

Comment: You may be interested in [this](https://github.com/tzuryby/jquery.hotkeys).

Comment: `onbeforeprint` and `onafterprint` will only work in IE and Firefox 6+ so don't rely on them.  See my answer for more details.

Comment: @TJVanToll Thankfully it only has to work on IE :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work:

```
@media print {
    .ui-tabs-nav { display: none; }
    .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide { display: block !important; }
}
```

---

This is another shot in the dark (i haven't tried it) but:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.onbeforeprint = destroyTabs;

     function destroyTabs(){
       $('#tabs').tabs('destroy').tabs();
     }
</script>
```

Comment: This hid the styling of the nav but it still prints just the tab that is visible not all of them (i forgot to mention that).

Comment: This works if I remove the .tabs();
I just googled documentation for that function (as i've never seen it) and found onafterprint. So i made a function to make the tabs after print is done. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this in JavaScript in a cross browser friendly way.

The `onbeforeprint` and `onafterprint` methods will only work in IE and Firefox 6+.  You can combine them with `window.matchMedia` to add support for Chrome 9+ and Safari 5.1+.  I've written about how to implement this at http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/.

Comment: Thankfully it only has to work on IE in this case. But your link is most definitely going into my bookmarks in case i need this cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).keypress("p",function(e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey)
    alert("Ctrl+P was pressed!!");
});
```

Comment: This will not catch the use of the "print" icon. Or "File > Print". Or a changed printing hotkey. Or `window.print()`.

Comment: @pekka this is, however, the answer to the question asked

Comment: I'm not worrying about the File>print just yet.
And for some reason this didn't fire. I pasted it exactly as is.