# Viewing the print CSS before printing

Tags: javascript, html, css

For printing differently from what is rendered on the screen, we use @media print rule.
Well and good.
But I want to display in browser window what exactly is going to be printed before the print dialog box pops up.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803151/how-to-trigger-media-query-on-user-demand-with-javascript

Comment: The problem is not with resizing.I want to display what is going to be printed on the browser window.

Comment: An idea completely out of the box may be to use an iframe that sets its `head` `meta` as a printer and not a web page? But I don't know how to do that, technically, if possible.

Comment: @user3930007, same logic should apply

Comment: Browsers come with Print Preview options. Let the user use them. There's no need to reproduce common built-in functionality.

Comment: @Quentin Yes of course, do you know if the `@media print` kicks in, cross browser, as it does when using `window.print()`?

Comment: @LGSon — Should do. It would be a pretty awful print preview if it previewed the screen stylesheet!

Comment: FWIW, a library exists for this very problem (nice print preview in-browser): `Paper CSS` https://github.com/cognitom/paper-css --- PS: If searching the web, don't confuse the library it with the "Paper CSS" framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same concept from this post, [How to trigger media query on user demand with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803151/how-to-trigger-media-query-on-user-demand-with-javascript), but instead you trigger/toggle a class name of your body tag, named say `previewprint`, with a button.

And your css could look like this:

```
body.previewprint .yourclass {
   property: value;
}

@media print {
  .yourclass {
    property: value;
  }
}
```

One way is to add a separate "Preview" button which sets the `previewprint` and the "Print" button reset/clear it.

If you don't want to have double css rules, then just using just the `previewprint` class would be fine if you open the page in a new window with the "Preview" button, and once there, users can click "Print" button. In this case the "print css rules" is already set and no need for a media query.

If to only use a "Print" button, do the same and then execute `window.print()` on load.

I also found this nice post, [how to detect window.print() finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325025/how-to-detect-window-print-finish), where you can do some cool stuff when a print finishes.

To intercept Ctrl+P, here is a few posts showing how that can be done:

- [Fire javascript function when ctrl+p is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349129/fire-javascript-function-when-ctrlp-is-pressed)
- [How to listen for Ctrl-P key press in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517819/how-to-listen-for-ctrl-p-key-press-in-javascript)

Comment: Your solution works fine. But can we do it without duplication?

Comment: @user3930007 Updated my answer slightly, to show a way without duplicate rules ... this also make it more "old browser friendly", for browsers who don't support media queries.

Comment: this also works but if a user presses ctrl+P, then no action will be triggered.

Comment: These 2 posts shows some ways to intercept ctrl+P: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349129/fire-javascript-function-when-ctrlp-is-pressed and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517819/how-to-listen-for-ctrl-p-key-press-in-javascript